# Replacing <nobr> elements in JSoup

Tags: java, html, jsoup, element, nobr

An HTML page can have nested `<nobr>` elements with or without preceding spaces, e.g.

```
<p>Paragraph with a <nobr>first element preceded by space</nobr> and a<nobr>second element not preceded by space</nobr>, just by text.</p>
```

Given this mix, there is no blanket rule for removing `<nobr>`, because if it is replaced by a leading space it will result in 2 spaces before the first element, whereas if it is not replaced by anything the second element will be joined with the preceding text, yielding `...asecond element...`, instead of `...a second element...`.

Is there any way of doing the replacement of `<nobr>` in one pass using the `Document` tree of `JSoup`, without string processing, so that only 1 space is left in all cases?

Comment: Your snippet is rendered in firefox as : "Paragraph with a first element preceded by space and asecond element not preceded by space, just by text." With "asecond" then I don't think jsoup will provide a means of splitting that without string processing.

Comment: I would try regexp but I think that would fall into "string processing".